# How to get the current products in cart in Magento?

Tags: magento

> I need to get the currently products in cart to estimate how many
>   products are in ? I used the below code but it gave me this error
>   message
>   **> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection::getAllItems()**
>
> Code:

```
    <?php

      require 'app/Mage.php';
      Mage::app();

     if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
        echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";

}

     $cart =Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
           foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
                   $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
                   $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();

          print($item);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that the best way is just create API User and Password from magento admin then use below code.

```
$userName = 'API USER';
$key = 'API KEY';
$userId = 'USER ID';

$client = new SoapClient(Mage::getBaseUrl().'api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login($userName, $key);

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($userId);
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer);
$quoteId = $quote->getId();

$cartInfo = $client->call($session, 'cart.info', $quoteId);
foreach($cartInfo['items'] as $i=>$item)
{
    echo $item['product_id'];
    echo $item['sku'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your code :

```
$cart =Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
```

It should be :

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$quote = $cart->getQuote();
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
      $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
      $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();

      print($item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this below code.

$totalItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCount();

For more details refer this link : http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/magento-get-product-quantity-in-cart/